# gcc linking multiple libraries?

Tags: gcc, linker

I have 18 Folders, in each one roughly between 3000 and 5000 object files. In each Folder  use the `ar cr *.o libX.a` to make an archive. Now I have 18 `libX.a` files. How can I make just one library from these 18 libraries?

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Have you thought of perhaps putting more than one line of code in each object file? That's quite a lot of them :-)

Comment: yes, but that is the number of functions, which I generated with mathematica automatically. I do not know another way to get fewer functions or object files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a thin archive with this command:

```
ar qT libOneLibrary.a lib*.a
```

where `lib*.a` stands for all 18 libraries. If these libraries are in different folder your need to specify the paths.

Verify that all the .o files are in there:

```
ar tv libOneLibrary.a
```

I revealed this feature by starting `ar` without any options. It shows you the meaning of the used options too.

Comment: thank you that works fine, however I have a question I tried without option "T" then I got an error. What dose this option mean?